# How to perform division in modular arithmetic on complex exponentials: controversy, bugfix required

Tags: fourier-analysis, modular-arithmetic

I have a complex exponent with prime divisor 7:

$e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{7}}$ and want to take it to the power 1/3:

$e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{7 \cdot 3}}$ (I'm learning, how to work with division in [multiplicative group of integers modulo prime number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) in case of Fourier exponentials).

My naive judgment of how to perform this operation leads me to the following controversy:

on one hand: $e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{7 \cdot 3}} = {e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{7}}}^{\frac{1}{3}} = {(e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{7}} \cdot 1)}^{\frac{1}{3}} = {(e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{7}} \cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 7}{7}})}^{\frac{1}{3}} = {e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 9}{7}}}^{\frac{1}{3}} = e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 9}{7\cdot 3}} = e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 3}{7}}$

on the other hand: $e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{7 \cdot 3}} = {(e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{3}})}^{\frac{1}{7}} = {(e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{3}} \cdot 1^4)}^{\frac{1}{7}} = {(e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{3}} \cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 3\cdot4}{3}})}^{\frac{1}{7}} = {(e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 14}{3}})}^{\frac{1}{7}} = e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 14}{3\cdot 7}} = e^{\frac{2\pi i \cdot 2}{3}}$

There should be some obvious error, but my mind is blindfolded now and I can't find it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using $j$ where the rest of us use $i$? And are you writing, for example, $2\pi j2$ where the rest of us would write $4\pi j$?

Comment: That's common in Electrical Engineering where Fourier Analysis is used a lot, but $i$ is used to indicate current, so they use $j$ for the complex unit.

Comment: @GerryMyerson :) Well, I usually write "i", too, but "in the disciplines of electrical engineering and control systems engineering, the imaginary unit is often denoted by j instead of i, because i is commonly used to denote electric current in these disciplines." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit. As I was using python right before posting the question, my head was in an EE mood :) As for $2\pi j \cdot 2$, I prefer to always leave $2\pi i$ intact, as it is always there and only change divisor and multiplier of it.

Comment: @Daniel, I understand that, but there is no electrical engineering, and no Fourier analysis, and no current, in this problem, so no call for $j$.

Comment: @Daniel, oddly enough, I just came across a column calling on mathematicians to follow the electrical engineers, and use $j$ for $\sqrt{-1}$: http://horizonsaftermath.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/i-cant-stand-it-anymore.html

Comment: Interesting argument in the article.  I think people should be flexible in their notation, as long as they document when necessary and aren't too unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the notation $\root n\of z$. This does not specify a single number. It could be any one of $n$ different numbers. E.g., $$1=e^0=e^{2\pi i}=e^{4\pi i}$$ is certainly true, but if you try to do $$\root3\of1=e^{0/3}=e^{2\pi i/3}=e^{4\pi i/3}$$ you find yourself writing nonsense.

In your problem, there are three equally well-qualified candidates for $\root3\of{e^{4\pi i/7}}$ and seven candidates for $\root7\of{e^{4\pi i/3}}$ and you have found examples of numbers that are in one list and not the other.

Comment: +1 The main problem I see is the use of the word "the" which implies singularity.  "The root of X" is a bad choice of phrase because X can have many roots, leading to all kinds of mischief.  I've never seen where assuming the existence of a  "primary root" helps either.  You either have to take a multi-valued approach to roots or sacrifice some properties of exponents.

Comment: Thanks for answering; but the problem is not in root: I'm sorry, cause root is a bad notation, but it doesn't solve it. With power notation the problem remains: ${e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}}^{\frac{1}{7}}$. Just in some traditions root is not a function (i.e. it returns multiple results).

Comment: @DanielV I've edited my question, replacing ambiguous root notation with unambiguous power notation. The problem seems to remain. Thanks for interest.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you write it as a root or as a power. $1=e^0=e^{2\pi i}=e^{4\pi i}$, but it's not true that $e^{0/3}=e^{2\pi i/3}=e^{4\pi i/3}$.